# If I have two lists, how do I export their values into a excel file?

Tags: python

If I have two lists such as this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]

y = [5, 6, 8]
```

how do I take both the lists and write them to a csv file so that list x appears in first row and list y appears in the next row such as this:

1 5

2 6

3 8

Sorry for not showing code, here it is for proof that I am not just leeching..

```
        file_out = open('file.csv','wb')
        mywriter=csv.writer(file_out, delimiter = '\n')
        mywriter.writerow([x_list])
        file_out.close()
```

problem is, when I try to do same thing with my y list it just replaces the first row again which i set to x list.

Edit again:

```
        open("file.csv", "w")
        file_out = open('file.csv','wb')
        mywriter=csv.writer(file_out, delimiter = '\n')
        for i in range(0, len(x_list)):
                mywriter.writerow([x_list[i], y_list[i]])
        file_out.close()
```

new problem, it prints all my x and ys in the same row still. My ys just won't go to next row.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Try googling your question.

Comment: I have only discovered how to write one lsit to the first row, but when ever I try to write the second list to csv file, it always rewrites the first row. I don't know how to make it so that it writes to the enxt row for next list.

Comment: Show us the code then

Comment: There you go, my code

Comment: Never felt so put down after asking a question on a forum.

Comment: @user152573: Maybe the reason is, that Stackoverflow is not a forum.

Comment: @user152573 not exactly a forum anyway ;) There's plenty of examples of how to do this sort of thing out there, e.g. http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the indices of the lists and write the value of an array of the value of x[i] and y[i]. For example,

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    csvwriter.writerow([x[i], y[i]])
```

Right now, you are just telling it to output a single row containing all of the values of x.

**Edit**

In your current code, some of the code was extraneous. One clear issue was that you opened the file as "wb" instead of "w". "wb" opens the file in binary mode, which is not appropriate for your usage. The following code worked for me in both Python 2.7 and 3.4:

```
import csv

x_list = [1, 2, 3]
y_list = [5, 6, 8]
with open('file.csv', 'w') as file_out:
    mywriter = csv.writer(file_out)
    for i in range(len(x_list)):
        mywriter.writerow([x_list[i], y_list[i]])
```

Comment: you don't need to specify 0 in your range.

Comment: Yup, you're right. No idea why I just did that.

Comment: I've tried something similar to this ebfore I asked, but it would always give me this thing saying it was out of the range

Comment: Are x and y the same length?

Comment: They are the same number of values in "int" form.

Comment: In that case, I don't know where that error came from. Could you implement it and see if it works?

Comment: It is working now, but the items are not being sent to file. I have added in the file_out.close() code as well.. hmm Might be my indentation?

Comment: Post the code and I'll see if I can help

Comment: Can you start a discussion chat, so I cans how you my code?

Comment: You don't have enough reputation, unfortunately. Just edit your original post.

Comment: Thank you for support, I managed to fix it as well after trial and error(dumb luck of inputting code). I tried your last solution as well and it worked.!!!!